# Call a View and wait until the window is closed is viable in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, architecture

I have a specific situation in my code where it would be very good to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
aView = new View();
aView.Show();
doSomething();
```

and I want the "doSomething()" to run only after the "aView" window closes. Is this viable/suitable to do in MVVM? If so, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MVVM its a good idea to seperate your logic from your view to keep your code testable. You could put your view-related code (aView = new View()... etc.) in some kind of service and pass that to your viewmodel. For testing your viewmodel logic you could then create a dummy test implementaion of that service.

Here´s an example:

```
public interface IViewService
{
    void ShowViewAndWaitForClosing(Action _onViewClosed);    
}
```

Create an implementaion of the service interface:

```
class ViewService : IViewService
{
    void ShowViewAndWaitForClosing(Action _onViewClosed)
    {
        AView view = new AView();
        view.Show();
        view.Closed += (o, e) => { _onViewClosed(); };
    }
}
```

Instantiate your service implementation somewhere and pass it to your logic/viewmodel. A good way to do this is to use a IOC-Container. For more information about that check out the [ViewmodelLocator class with MVVM Light Framework](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Templates/CSharp/ProjectTemplates/Mvvm.WPF/ViewModelLocator.cs).

```
class SomeViewModel
{
    private IViewService mViewService;

    public SomeViewMode(IViewService _viewService)
    {
        mViewService = _viewService;

        //Whenever you need to show your View call:
        mViewService.ShowViewAndWaitForClosing(doSomething);
    }

    private void doSomething() 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Since you can not easily open and itneract with views when softwaretesting your viewmodel, create a testimplementation of your service that fakes the closing of your view immediately after your method call.

```
class TestViewService : IViewService
{
    void ShowViewAndWaitForClosing(Action _onViewClosed)
    {
        _onViewClosed();
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        blah............................

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

put this in aview backend

Answer (score 0):

```
  doSomething();
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
          aView = new View();
           aView.Show();
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Use above the code for meet your requirement.